# "Imprimir" Tkinter Canvas en un archivo PDF

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, canvas

Tengo una pequeña herramienta que genera unos gráficos y los muestro en un Canvas. Me gustaría crear un archivo PDF generado a partir del canvas, estoy intentando esta solución  pero no me funciona:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877495/python-tkinter-save-canvas-as-postscript-and-add-to-pdf?lq=1

Hay alguna biblioteca para hacer esto que quiero? El canvas tiene scroll.

Comment: La solución que enlazas guarda el canvas como PostScript y luego convierte el PostScript en pdf (lo cual require tener instalado ghostscript, razón por la que seguramente te falla). Es un camino enrevesado, pero ya que el canvas no tiene conversor a pdf parece que es la única forma.

Comment: Si que tengo instalado Ghostscript por eso no entiendo porque falla :(

Comment: ¿Puedes dar más detalles con respecto al fallo? ¿Se produce una excepción? ¿Qué mensaje de error? ¿No se produce error pero no genera el pdf? ¿Genera un pdf vacío?

Comment: Es muy raro también porque: 
NO se produce ninguna excepción ni mensaje de error.
NO se genera el PDF ni siquiera vacío.

Comment: Pues no sé qué decirte. Yo acabo de probar el ejemplo que ponen en el enlace que proporcionas, y me ha funcionado. Me ha generado un pdf con una página en blanco. Si, por otro lado, en vez de `ps2pdf` pongo un comando que no exista, al ejecutar el script python y darle al botón de convertir me sale por consola "no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo...etc"